# Adding proportions to a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I've used my df to create a filled bar chart (Code used below). I want to have the proportions of each "race" printed within the bar chart.

```
Demo_17 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(Race_17, -c("State",), names_to = "Race", values_to = "num") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=State, y=num, fill = Race)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")

  Demo_17 + 
  labs(x = "Population", y = "State", title = "US State Demographics 2017")
```

This is the df I'm using: [US Demographic Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7YnW.png)

I've looked at other similar questions but the code is long and hard to follow, particularly if it doesn't relate to your own data.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Thank you for sharing your data with your question, but sharing your dataset should be managed by posting the results of `dput(your.data.frame)`.  This exports your dataset as text that can be easily copy/pasted into the console to accurately recreate the dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Simply compute shares before plotting. Use `scales::percent` for nice formatting:

```
Demo_17 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(Race_17, -c("State",), names_to = "Race", values_to = "num") %>% 
  # compute pct share of race by state
  group_by(State) %>% 
  mutate(pct = num / sum(num)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=State, y=num, fill = Race)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(pct)), position = "fill")

Demo_17 + labs(x = "Population",
               y = "State",
               title = "US State Demographics 2017")
```

An example of this approach using `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl, gear, name = "num") %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(pct = num / sum(num)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cyl, y=num, fill = gear)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(pct)), position = "fill", vjust = 1.5, color = "white")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**ADDITIONALLY:** If you prefer to only show a label for shares over 10% (just an example, adjust as wished) then you add an `ifelse()` inside the `label` argument of `geom_text`:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl, gear, name = "num") %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(pct = num / sum(num)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cyl, y=num, fill = gear)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(pct>0.10, scales::percent(pct), "")), position = "fill", vjust = 1.5, color = "white")
```

[image]

As you notice the 9% label is not showing anymore.

Comment: That's great. Worked well for me. Only issue being the labels are overlapping...would you know how to fix this?

Comment: @AndrewJudge From the image of your dataset I would guess that the overlapping occurs for the races with only small shares in the total population. Unfortunately there is no perfect solution to this. One option would be to lump small groups together. Or have a look at `ggrepel::geom_text_repel` which does its best to label the data so that there is no overlapping. Sometimes this works great, sometimes ... (;

Comment: Great attempt @stefan considering the lack of a dataset too. The problem with labels overlapping can be solved with an ```ifelse()``` condition inside the ```geom_text()```. However, it means that you simply don't print the labels for some races of very small proportion.

Comment: If you are okay with me editing your solution to include the ifelse() let me know. Of course only if @AndrewJudge prefers the idea of the very small proportions not having a label.

Comment: @Yach Thx. Feel free to edit my post. For me this is fine. It's indeed another good option to solve the problem with the labels.

Comment: Hey @stefan thanks, I have updated long time now but it's pending approval.

Comment: @Yach Just approved. Did a ride on my bike. (;

Comment: Hi @Yach! very happy for you to do so. and thanks to both of you for your help @stefan

Comment: Cool @AndrewJudge it is already updated. Remember to approve Stefan's solution which is the most complete (in case it helped with your problem always) so that others who navigate to your question in the future can certainly know that there is a confirmed answer to it. Cheers and welcome.

Answer (score 1):

What adds the labels to your charts is the `geom_text()`. Maybe something like this:

```
Demo_17 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(Race_17, -c("State",), names_to = "Race", values_to = "num") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=State, y=num, fill = Race)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")

  Demo_17 + 
  labs(x = "Population", y = "State", title = "US State Demographics 2017") +
  geom_text(aes(y=num, x=State, labels=num), vjust=0.5)
```

Can't test if it works great like this or if it needs some modifications since you have only supplied a screenshot of your dataset instead of a reproducible example of it. Let me know if it works but if it needs more attention read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people can effectively help you.